# Select :last-child, but with specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Assume I have this unordered list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="item"></li>
   <li class="placeholder"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm doing some ordering where `.item` can be sorted and if it is last .item in the list it will be moved to other list. I would regularly use `:last-child` however if there is a `.placeholder` element in there it will not recognise last item as it should and will instead think that because of placeholder the item is not last.
How could I make it so it selects last `.item` only??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `:last` selector or `.last()` method on object of item elements:

```
$('.item:last');//will give third li
```

or

```
$('.item').last();//will give third li
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `:last` one:

```
$('.item:last');
```

> Note that :last selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it.

If you are concerned with performance, use:

```
$(".item").filter(":last");
```